# How does Evernote Web Clipper know which webpage I copied text from?

Tags: delphi, clipboard, copy-paste, evernote

I select text on a webpage and copy it to the clipboard (Ctrl-C).
Then I open an Evernote note and paste that text there (Ctrl-V).
Evernote then places a link to the webpage in the note's header.

How does Evernote know that? Does the Windows clipboard hold information about a text's origin apart from the text itself?

Extra credit:
I'd like to store this information the same way in a Delphi 10 application I'm writing.

Comment: "Does the Windows clipboard hold information about a text's origin apart from the text itself?" Yes, if the browser puts it in there.

Comment: The Windows Clipboard can contain more then just plain text (think of images and so). Besides that, when something is put on the clipboard (using Ctrl+C) multiple formats can be added to represent the item put on the clipboard. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-formats